# Preserve keys when convert multi dimensional array to one dimensional

Tags: php

I can't figure out how to correctly flatten this array. So, I loose the keys when I flattened using array_unique. So, This is the original array:

```
  array:9 [
  0 => array:1 [
    2 => "Opnam"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [
    2 => "Opnam"
  ]
  2 => array:1 [
    2 => "Opnam"
  ]
  3 => array:1 [
    3 => "Voem"
  ]
  4 => array:1 [
    8 => "And"
  ]
  5 => array:1 [
    6 => "Vei"
  ]
  6 => array:1 [
    6 => "Vei"
  ]
  7 => array:1 [
    8 => "And"
  ]
  8 => array:1 [
    8 => "And"
  ]
]

The is the expected output:
array:[
  2 => "Opnam"
  3 => "Voem"
  6 => "Vei"
  8 => "And"
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php ?

Comment: @AndreaManzi That doesn't maintain the keys of the inner arrays.

Comment: @Barmar this https://stackoverflow.com/a/308955/2776343?

Comment: That produces a 2-dimensional result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the key and value of the inner array, and use it as the key and value of the result.

```
$result = [];
foreach ($original as $inner) {
    foreach ($inner as $key => $value) {
        $result[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```